# Generate dynamic content in azure logic app

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to create such a body for my HTTP Task in azure logic APP

```
{
  "CommitMode": "transactional",
  "MaxParallelism": 20,
  "Objects": [
    {
      "partition": "Table_2019-03-27",
      "table": "Table"
    },
     {
      "partition": "Table_2019-03-28",
      "table": "Table"
    },
    {
      "partition": "Table_2019-03-29",
      "table": "Table"
    }
  ],
  "RetryCount": 0,
  "Type": "Full"
}
```

I would like to generate the body part automatically, as you can see only `partition` is changes and it is the combination of `Table_` and `Date` Do you have any Idea how can I implement such a thing in azure logic app?

Comment: Where and  how do you get these values? Are their numbers fixed? What is their initial format?

Comment: I would like to define a variable in my Logic App with a default value i.e 2019-03-27 and then I would like to generate next ten days and integrate them in my body

Comment: Is the date related to today’s date somehow?

Comment: @AdAstra it is not related to todays date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to refresh Azure Analysis Services through REST API.

Assumming you have date defined (or passed as parameter)

[image]

Then you create temporary variable for dates as follows

[image]

And now you create until loop which iterates until array will have length of amount of days you want. In this case 10, you can pass this as parameter.

[image]

First expression you see here is

```
length(variables('Dates'))
```

And the expression for append to array variable is

```
formatDateTime(addDays(variables('StartDate'), iterationIndexes('Until')),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Then simply create body as

[image]

Where expression here is

```
concat('{"partition": "Table_',join(variables('Dates'), '","table": "Table"},{"partition": "Table_'),'","table": "Table"}')
```

And your output will look like

```
{
  "CommitMode": "transactional",
  "MaxParallelism": 20,
  "Objects": [
    {"partition": "Table_2019-03-27","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-03-28","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-03-29","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-03-30","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-03-31","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-04-01","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-04-02","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-04-03","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-04-04","table": "Table"},
    {"partition": "Table_2019-04-05","table": "Table"}
  ],
  "RetryCount": 0,
  "Type": "Full"
}
```

If you want general recommendation on how to do this I have an article on how to do it rom logic app here

- from Logic App https://marczak.io/posts/2019/06/logic-apps-refresh-analysis-services/
- from Data Factory https://marczak.io/posts/2019/06/logic-app-vs-data-factory-for-aas-refresh/

And if you want to learn more about logic apps check my video series on Logic apps

- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGjZwEtPN7j_nFYA1qc7cWumNr89PkfAX

Full code for reference

```
{
  "definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "actions": {
      "Initialize_Body": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "body",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "{\n  \"CommitMode\": \"transactional\",\n  \"MaxParallelism\": 20,\n  \"Objects\": [\n  @{concat('{\"partition\": \"Table_',join(variables('Dates'), '\",\"table\": \"Table\"},{\"partition\": \"Table_'),'\",\"table\": \"Table\"}')}\n  ],\n  \"RetryCount\": 0,\n  \"Type\": \"Full\"\n}"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Until": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Initialize_Start_Date": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "StartDate",
              "type": "String",
              "value": "2019-03-27"
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {},
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Initialize_variable": {
        "inputs": {
          "variables": [
            {
              "name": "Dates",
              "type": "Array",
              "value": []
            }
          ]
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Initialize_Start_Date": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "InitializeVariable"
      },
      "Until": {
        "actions": {
          "Append_to_array_variable": {
            "inputs": {
              "name": "Dates",
              "value": "@formatDateTime(addDays(variables('StartDate'), iterationIndexes('Until')),'yyyy-MM-dd')"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
          }
        },
        "expression": "@equals(length(variables('Dates')), 10)",
        "limit": {
          "count": 60,
          "timeout": "PT1H"
        },
        "runAfter": {
          "Initialize_variable": [
            "Succeeded"
          ]
        },
        "type": "Until"
      }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
      "manual": {
        "inputs": {
          "schema": {}
        },
        "kind": "Http",
        "type": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.If your data is fixed. You can use [Compose action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) to generate the json.

2.However, as you need to get the required dates by calculation, and there is no direct action in logic app for this, I suggest you create a function app to finish the job. You can directly call a function app in your logic app as the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions).

The function app will accept a date, and then generate the json for you.  And then you can use the returned json in your logic app.